# Gitlab CI / Gitlab Runner - Which version of gitlab-ci.yml is used?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Which version of `.gitlab-ci.yml` is actually been taken when running CI-Jobs in a MergeRequest?

Is it the version provided in the

- source-branch,
- target-branch,
- or master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The runner checks out the *source-branch*!**

If the branch does not contain all commits of the master branch it is marked as 'detached'. In that case it is advisable to rebase the branch to the master. Otherwise a red state may occur at merge time.

There are more enhanced checkout/merge/test strategies called [Merge Trains](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/pipelines_for_merged_results/merge_trains/), but that is another topic.